# How to filter in sql to show certain text

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

In where clause I have

```
Select B.ID,
       B.TIME_1,
       B.TIME_2,
       a.event_type,
       a.jew,
       c.dist
from B, table1 a left outer join table3 c on a.jew = c.mew
Where B.ID = A.ID
AND a.event_type in ('APPLE','ORANGE','GRAPE')
```

My Problem is my querty doesn't show if for example some records of ID doesn't all 3 (apple,orange,grape). I would still like to pull all ID even if it doesn't have all 3 or none of Apple orange, Grape.

Example:
Lets say my database has total of 5 records

ID=`1` has event type of `Apple`, `Orange`, `Grape` also has none but it has others also I don't care about it
ID=`2` `Apple` 
ID=`3` `Orange`  
ID=`4` `Apple`,`Orange` `Grape`  
ID=`5` none of 3 but others I don't care about

So currently my query is just pulling where ID=1, I want to modify where it pulls all 5 condition.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Can you make an example with some relevant data and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want any of the three event types or none.  For this, use left outer joins but put all the conditions in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT B.ID, B.TIME_1, B.TIME_2, A.event_type, A.jew, C.dist
FROM B left outer join
     table1 A 
     ON B.ID = A.ID and
        A.event_type in ('APPLE','ORANGE','GRAPE') LEFT OUTER JOIN
     table3 C 
     ON A.jew = C.mew
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a left join also with your table1, and add a condition in case there is no match between B and table1:

```
SELECT B.ID,
       B.TIME_1,
       B.TIME_2,
       A.event_type,
       A.jew,
       C.dist
FROM B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 A 
        ON B.ID = A.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 C 
                ON A.jew = C.mew
WHERE A.event_type IS NULL
OR A.event_type in ('APPLE','ORANGE','GRAPE')
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and I am still missing records which only has `Apple` in it.